# JS: Changing value in function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, button

I've made an  which displays a arrow pointing down. The idea is that if the user clicks on this, the navigation bar will be shown. So far it works but I wanted that when the  is pressed, it's value and rotation changes as well. However the value doesn't change. Can someone please help me with what i'm doing wrong. Thanks! 
The screenshots: 
[image: Javascript code which doesn't work] 
[image: HTML that belongs to the Javascript]

Comment: Add the relevant code here at SO

Comment: Please, copy/past your code here or link to Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no proper "value" Attribute for `<h3>` so it didn't work with `dropBut.value` I've done some changes in your code..

```
var dropBut = document.getElementById("dropDownBut");

function dropDownMenu(){
console.log("hey");
console.log(dropBut.getAttribute("value"));
    if(dropBut.getAttribute("value") === "downside"){
    dropBut.style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
    dropBut.setAttribute("value","upside");
  }
  else if(dropBut.getAttribute("value") === "upside"){
    dropBut.style.transform = "rotate(-270deg)";
    dropBut.setAttribute("value","downside");
  }
}

dropBut.addEventListener("click",dropDownMenu);
```

Hope this one helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is something using JQuery.

```
$('#dropdownButton').click(function(){  
    $('#dropdownButton').attr('value','up');//set with jquery  
    if($('#dropdownButton').attr('value')==='up')//compare value   
    {
          alert("UP!");   
    }   
    if($('#dropdownButton').attr('value')==='down')//compare value   
    {
         alert("DOWN!");   
    } 
    });
```